# float: right with <li> is not working

Tags: html

I have following code which works fine in firefox and ie 8, but in IE 7 the second li is coming with some top space instead of same line.

```
    <LI style="PADDING-LEFT: 20px">
           Sort by: <SELECT id=ddSortOrder class='content-select'> 
    <OPTION selected value=0>Recommended
    </OPTION></SELECT> 
    </LI>
    <LI id=lipageAnchors><<&nbsp;|&nbsp;<&nbsp;|&nbsp;Previous&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <A class=current title=1 >1</A>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <A title=2>2</A>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<A title=3 >3</A>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<A title=Next >Next</A>&nbsp;|&nbsp;>&nbsp;|&nbsp;>></LI>
```

The First `<li>` comes in left as expected but the second `<li>` should float to right, but it is to right with some extra space. I want both the `<li>` in same line (position), which works in firefox and IE 8 but in IE 7 is not.

Image link [alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/viewpic.php?p=1275649526056730400&x=jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/viewpic.php?p=1275649526056730400&x=jpg)
http://www.imagechicken.com/viewpic.php?p=1275649526056730400&x=jpg

Please help!

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: can you please fix the code so it can be readable? also screenshots if you have em please

Comment: I'm with corroded. You've been on SO for 11 months and asked 24 other questions, formatting questions shouldn't still be an issue. Click the **[?]** link on the Ask a Question page: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Yep, posted the edited code and screen shot.

Comment: Are you using a DOCTYPE that puts IE7 in Standards mode?

Comment: usually a float: left; is all you need. But first you have to clean up your code. And a screenshot isn't very useful, as we can't debug it. Please post a link to the page. And you question there is no float at all. And you haven't post your CSS so how are we going to find your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few html errors in your code.

Replace your `<` with `%lt;` and your `>` with `&gt;`.
Because `<&nbsp>` will render as a invalid html tag.

And remember to wrap your html-tag attributes values within `"` (double quotes) like this:

`<li id="lipageAnchors"><!-- Content goes here --></li>`

And to answer your question about the `float:right`, put it on the `<ul>` tag. You might also set a width on it to be sure you get it to the right.

I Hope this will be to any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the following html code:

```
</LI>
<LI>
```

You should be fine if you put them into one line.

Comment: I think browser ignore the space between the tags, we need to give &nbsp; to render space.

Comment: Actually IE has bugs concerning `li` and white space. It's best to leave no while space, especially **between** the `li`s. And CSS `margin` is used to render space, not `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Actualy a SPACE is used for normal spacing. There is not need for &nbsp; if you use only one space.